# Rearrange the order of rows in a database according to the ascending order of date in a column in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview

I have an sqlite database in which there are several rows and columns and one column contains date and time.I have to rearrange the whole database according to the ascending order of that date and time column How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cursor cursor = this.db.query(TABLE_NAME_2, new String[] { "empid,username,emp_date,imagepath"},
              null , null, null, null, "empid asc");
```

you can also give `empid desc` for descending order of the empid..

Answer (score 1):

```
"select * from " + DB_TABLE + " order by " + KEY_DATE + " asc";
```

Thats will do!

Comment: For using this piece of code what should be the datatype of KEY_DATE? I am using string here.Actually m new to database and i dont know how to query. I added this code as sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{
  KEY_ID,KEY_CONTENT1,KEY_CONTENT2,KEY_CONTENT3,KEY_CONTENT4,KEY_CONTENT5,KEY_CONTENT6,KEY_CONTENT7,KEY_CONTENT8  
  },"select * from " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " order by " + KEY_CONTENT8 + " asc", null, null, null, null); and I am gettin force close.What should i do?